# $\alpha \cdot (\alpha+1) \cdots (\alpha + n -1)\frac{1}{n!} \sim \frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)}n^{\alpha-1} \; \text{as} \; n \to \infty$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, asymptotics, gamma-function

This is Exercise 4 from Chapter 6 of Stein and Shakarchi's Complex Analysis.

Prove that if we take 
$$f(z) = \frac{1}{(1-z)^\alpha}, \; \text{for } |z|<1$$ (defined in terms of the principal branch of the logarithm), where $\alpha$ is a fixed complex number, then 
$$f(z)= \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(\alpha)z^n$$ with $$a_n(\alpha) \sim \frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)}n^{\alpha-1} \; \text{as} \; n \to \infty.$$

It is easy to see that $a_n(\alpha) =\alpha \cdot (\alpha+1) \cdots (\alpha + n -1)\frac{1}{n!}$.

But I can't figure out how to show that grows as $\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)}n^{\alpha - 1}$ as $n\to \infty$. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Is $\mathcal{Re}(\alpha)>0$? What is your definition of $\Gamma$?

Comment: Observe that $ a_{n}\left(\alpha\right)=\frac{\alpha\left(\alpha +1\right)\cdots\left(\alpha +n-1\right)}{n!}=\frac{\Gamma\left(\alpha +n\right)}{n!\Gamma\left(\alpha\right)} $, then use Stirling's formula.

Comment: @CHAMSI Using Stirling's formula of the form $\Gamma(s) \sim \sqrt{2 \pi} s^{s-1/2} e^{-s}$, I get $\Gamma(\alpha+n)/\Gamma(1+n) \sim \frac{\alpha+n}{1+n}^{\alpha + n-1/2} (1+n)^{\alpha - 1} e^{1-\alpha}$. So this $\sim n^{\alpha-1} e^{1-\alpha}$. How do I get rid of this exponential?

Comment: Since $ \Gamma\left(\alpha +n\right)\underset{n\to +\infty}{\sim}\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{\alpha +n}}\left(\frac{\alpha +n}{\mathrm{e}}\right)^{\alpha +n} $, and $ \Gamma\left(1 +n\right)\underset{n\to +\infty}{\sim}\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{1 +n}}\left(\frac{1 +n}{\mathrm{e}}\right)^{1 +n} $, we get $ \frac{\Gamma\left(\alpha +n\right)}{n!}\underset{n\to +\infty}{\sim}\frac{\left(\alpha +n\right)^{\alpha +n}}{\left(n+1\right)^{n+1}}\,\mathrm{e}^{1-\alpha}=\left(\alpha +n\right)^{\alpha -1}\left(1+\frac{\alpha -1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}\,\mathrm{e}^{1-\alpha}\underset{n\to +\infty}{\sim}n^{\alpha -1} \cdot $

Comment: (I used the fact that $ \lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}{\left(1+\frac{z}{n}\right)^{n}}=\mathrm{e}^{z} $ for any complex $ z $)

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you know the solution to Exercise 1 from the same chapter. The proof below uses its result that $\Gamma(s) = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n^s s!}{s(s+1)\cdots(s+n)}$.

By taking the n-th derivative of $\frac{1}{(1-z)^\alpha} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(\alpha) z^n$ on both sides and setting $z=0$, we have

$a_n(\alpha) = \alpha \cdot (\alpha+1) \cdots (\alpha+n-1) \frac{1}{n!}.$

Noticing how similar this looks to the formula for $\Gamma(s)$ given above, we have

$a_n(\alpha) = \frac{\alpha \cdot (\alpha+1) \cdots (\alpha+n)n^\alpha}{(\alpha+n) n! n^\alpha} \sim \frac{n^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)(\alpha+n)} \sim \frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)} n^{\alpha-1}$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.